# When compiling, Android Manifest causes problems preventing it from running?

Tags: java, android

I'm rather new to Android Studio, so I've been trying to make this note taking app.

It was running fine this morning up to when I had to make a menu to add notes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_note" android:title="Add Note"  ></item>
```

this is made to create a menu where I can add notes and stuff, but after referencing it in my MainActivity and my NoteEditing activity respectively and compiling, it started acting up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myjournal">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".NoteEditorActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

in specific, I don't have a **android:theme="@style/AppTheme">** or a **android:label="@/app_name"**
and I have no idea where the program got those from. If I changing these two and running it, it crashes ex. I changed android theme to the title of "Add Note" and it crashed

I never coded either of these two in an xml document though and I haven't found a 'styles.xml' in my files. I'm really stumped here--any help would be appreciated in fixing this issue!
Edit: woops! The error i've been recieving  is

**Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\mrwad\AndroidStudioProjects\MyJournal\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-20:19: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.example.myjournal:style/AppTheme) not found.**

Comment: Could you post the errors you're receiving?  It's hard to tell what's going wrong just from your description.  (Also, are you sure it's not supposed to be `@string/app_name`?)

Comment: woops! yeah of course the error i've getting is    


Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\mrwad\AndroidStudioProjects\MyJournal\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-20:19: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.example.myjournal:style/AppTheme) not found.

and yeah i'll try that @string/app_name out, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, ok so I think I understand what is happening.

So you say you don't have a strings.xml, I'm assuming your styles.xml is also not setup properly either.

So in an Android project, you should have a directory called `values` under `res`:

- app -> src -> main/

  - res/

    - layout
    - values

      - strings.xml
      - colors.xml
      - styles.xml
    - (Other resource folders you might have)

Within this `values` directory lies important resources that the project uses.  This includes strings, styles, colors, etc.

So if you are lacking a app theme, ensure that a theme exists in your styles (The error is pointing to `style/AppTheme`.  Here is an example `styles.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

These colors can be stored in a `colors.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Lastly, your `app_name` should reside in a `strings.xml` file:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My New App</string>
</resources>
```

If any of these files are missing, then just create the above files under the `values` directory within `app/src/main/res/`. You'll notice as you develop that android does not like hard-coded values, and whenever you want to write a String, or Color, etc. It will prompt you to create a resource entry in one of the above files to use instead.

I highly recommend going through some of the android documentation, they have a very verbose set of documentation.  You can learn more about resource management [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

Answer (score 0):

android:label="@string/app_name" you are missing the string.
you can see those values in res/values directory.

[image]

Comment: When I check for the values directory, they don't seem to be there for some reason? I'm not sure--I could of deleted them on accident? Is it possible to create a new values folder? https://prnt.sc/s6f0kx

Comment: yeah you can make styles.xml    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: string.xml     and keep this resources <resources>
<string name="app_name">your application name</string>

</resources>